# Automating SSAS 2012 Deployment?

Tags: deployment, automation, ssas-2012

Not using TFS. I can build via devenv and run the deployment commandline with /O to create an XMLA file, but how to deploy the XMLA? Apparently ASCMD doesn't work in SQL 2012? Most of the posts and docs I've read are from SQL 2005/2008. I've not seen anything that specifically addresses how to deploy to SSAS 2012...

Comment: Nothing? Nobody? Wow. That doesn't happen often...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Microsoft BI Support the correct process to deploy an XMLA file is to use PowerShell's Invoke-ASCmd cmdlet. This is Microsoft's supported replacement for the old ASCMD utility.